# Trouble automating creation of properties

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties

I am trying to automate the creation of properties and don't even know where to begin tracking this down.  Clearly I have a gap in my understanding of how 'prop' is treated in this example.

```
def makecls():
    cls = type('mycls', (object,), {})
    for prop in ['hi', 'bye']:
        def fget(self):
            return prop
        setattr(cls, prop, property(fget, doc=prop)
    return cls
```

In the case of the doc, prop seems to persist

In the case of the value returned by fget, prop seems to be the last value in the loop ('bye').

```
>>> cls = makecls()
>>> y = cls()
>>> y.hi, y.bye
('bye', 'bye')                         #expecting ('hi', 'bye')
>>> cls.hi.__doc__, cls.bye.__doc__
('hi', 'bye')                          #got expected result
>>> cls.hi.fget, cls.bye.fget
(<function fget at 0x062C92F0>, <function fget at 0x062C93B0>)
```

Comment: this explains what is going on ... still need help on how to solve as i don't think i can use the binding in the getter ... will experiment

Comment: the factory fixes the problem